# Simple html dom parser - find value in attribute

Tags: php, parsing

```
<div class="bk-cell-wrapper">
<div class="bk-timetable-cell">
div class="day-item-hover" data-detail="{**value i want to find**}" >BlaBlaBlabLa</div>
</div>
</div>
```

from this pattern which repeats multipletimes, i want to extract all divs with attribute "data-detail" in it.
I made it  with this code :

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
  foreach($html->find('div[data-detail]') as $element )
  echo $element
```

now i want to extract the value in attribute "data-detail" from the variable $element, where i store each div with attr "data-detail" in it

view-source:https://oa-poruba.bakalari.cz/Timetable/Public/Actual/Class/WV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
$myDiv = $html->find('div[data-detail]');
  foreach($myDiv as $element ) {
    echo $element->getAttribute('data-detail');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package [php-html-parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser)

and get what you want like this:

```php
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;

$dom = new Dom;
$dom->loadStr('<div class="all"><p>Hey bro, <a href="google.com">click here</a><br /> :)</p></div>');
$a = $dom->find('a')[0];
echo $a->text; // "click here"
```

And also get the attribute like this:

```php
// Assuming you installed from Composer:
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;

$dom = new Dom;
$dom->loadFromFile('tests/data/big.html');
$contents = $dom->find('.content-border');
echo count($contents); // 10

foreach ($contents as $content)
{
    // get the class attr
    $class = $content->getAttribute('class');
}
```